# Launch app at a user specified time?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have an app that plays radio stations, and I now want to integrate an alarm clock such that it plays a radio station when the alarm goes off. I have been looking into the Alarm Manager, which seems to be the best way to do it.

My app has an alarm button which calls a dialog to set the alarm. If an alarm is set, I need to have my app start at the specified time. However, I am having trouble with this section of code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("some Context", null, null, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendInt = PendingIntent.getBroadcast("some Context", 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmService.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToSound, pendInt);
```

Specifically, I am confused about what `context` needs to be. I have seen many examples, but none really explain it in detail. I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this matter.
more code that might help...

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Dialog d = null;
        switch (id) {
        case LINEUP_DIALOG_ID:
            d = new LineupDialog(this);
            d.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = d.getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
            d.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            break;
```

this calls my dialog^

```
private View.OnClickListener lineupAction = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //showAlarm();
            showDialog(LINEUP_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    };
```

both of these are in my mainActivity.
then i have an xml file that holds the layouts (can be provided if needed.. just allows the user to chose a time and checkbox, then save)
save button has an onclickListener--- it is in my LineupDialog class that extends my NavDialog, and my navdialog just extends Dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that i needed to make a new class also... the part of the context worked by making a variable, and just if anyone else needs it, here is my code for the new service that i had to make.

```
//imports here
public class AlarmService extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("hello im in the alarmService Binder");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Intent mainAct = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        //System.out.println("hello im in the alarmService onStart " + mainAct);
        mainAct.setClass(AlarmService.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainAct.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mainAct.putExtra("alarm","true");
        startActivity(mainAct);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //System.out.println("hello im in the alarmService onCreate");
        //code to execute when the service is first created
    }

}
```

then dont forget to add it to your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Kyle,

It should be the package Context, but this can sometimes depend on where in your code you are creating the `Intent` and `PendingIntent`.  Have you just tried `this` or `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: yes i have tried both those... this says that it is a view.onclicklistener.. i am currently trying getOwnerActivity(), but again im shooting in the dark, i cant find a good explanation for this. any ideas... thanks

Comment: What were the results when you tried each method I mentioned?

Comment: 'this' errors and says there is not constructor with Intent(new view.onclicklistener(){}, ..) and 'getApplicationContext()' errors and says the method is undefined in view.onclickListener()

Comment: What kind of class is all this happening in?  Is it possible you could put more of the code up.  A few times I've had to make a member variable `Context mContext` then in `onCreate()` set it as `mContext = getApplicationContext` so I can still use it in things like `onClickListener()`.

Comment: more code has been provided above, sorry i didnt really know what to show, i think these are the key parts.

Comment: Ok, I would try creating a member variable containing the context as i suggested in my last comment.  This should work since you are in an `Activity`.